# C# folder and subfolder

Tags: forms, pdf, directory, subdirectory

Upon numerous searches, I am here to see if someone has any idea on how I should go about tackling this issue.
I have a folder with sub-folders.  The sub-folder containers each has files of different file types e.g. pdf, png, jpeg, tiff, avi and word documents.
My goal is to write a code in C# that will go into the subfolder, and combined all the files into one pdf using the name of the folder.  The only exception is that a file such as avi will not be pdf'ed in which case I want a nudge as to which folder it is and possibly file name.  I am trying to use the form approach, so that you can copy in the folder pathname and also destination of the created pdf.

Thanks.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

to start, create a FolderBrowserDialog to get the root folder.  Alternatively just make a textbox in which you paste the folder name ( less preferred since the first method gives you nicer error-handling straight out of the box )

In order to iterate through, see [How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx)
To find the filetype, check `System.IO.FileInfo.Extension` for each file you iterate through.  Add those to list with the data you need.  ( hint, create a list of objects in which your object reflects the data you need such as path, type etc,... ).  If its an avi don't toss it in the list but flash a warning (messagebox?) instead.

From here the original question gets fuzzy.  What exactly do you need in the pdf.  Just the filenames and locations or do you actually want to throw the actual contents of the file in pdf?

Comment: End goal is for all files in the folder/subfolder to become combined into a (*.pdf).  Also can this be done in forms/textbox or only in console.write

Comment: Any other recommendations please ?